# Multiple links in credtis, Highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is it possible to use more than 1 link as credtis?
Since I couldn't find anything in API or any other forum my approach would be to try to use a single `text` and single `href` and by some kind of parser break it into multiple links.
Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SVGRenderer tool to render a custom text with included `a href` link.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text